# Is there a way to switch from a Process thread back to the thread which originally created the Process upon exit?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono

```
public class SomeClass {
  static void Method() {
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "a command line util";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "some arguments";
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { 
      Debug.Log(e.Data); 
    };

    p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
      Debug.Log(e.Data);  
    };

    Thread mainThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
    p.Exited += (sender, e) => {
      if (p.ExitCode == 0) {
        // Need to do something in the thread which originally created p.
       //  I even got mainThread from above, but don't know if I can 'switch' to it.
      }
    };

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();
  }
```

My problem is basically this:

1. I'm in the "main" thread and create a process and start it.
2. I got about getting async events from the process.
3. By the time the process exits, the callback is still in a process's thread, but I need to do some other stuff in the "main" thread.

In case anyone is wondering why the static and why the need for all this, it's cause I'm on Unity (the game engine) and need a static method for executing code in a menu item. The menu item needs to generate an assets from a command line util and then cause Unity to refresh its assets dir to find the new asset. The problem is any calls to Unity code need to execute in the main thread and the minute I start getting the `Process` callbacks I'm no longer in the main thread.

**UPDATE** Just in case, I'm on Mono for Unity, which is aprox. .NET 3.5 without Windows specific stuff. So for instance, the Dispatcher class from System.Windows is not available.

Comment: Sure? It doesn't seem to. I tried putting the code I'd run on the main thread there and Unity bitched that the code needs to be run on the main thread..

Comment: No...that statement was just an assumption. Clearly it isn't if that's the error you get, if that's the case then you need to use `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to delegate the code to run back onto the main thread.

Comment: Those are from the Dispatcher class right? If so, I'm afraid they won't work for me since I don't have the System.Windows namespace. I'm on Mono for Unity, which is aprox. .NET 3.5 without Windows specific stuff. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: Well that changes things I guess, there does already seem to be a [discussion](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/128265/invoking-main-thread.html) about this on the unity3d site, might be of use to you.